# mysqldump restore error

Tags: mysql, mysqldump, amazon-rds

I am getting the error below, while restoring a dump to RDS MySQL 5.6. Dump is taken from MySQL 5.5 originally. I tried restoring twice but same error. Can anyone help

```
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 125596: You have an error in your SQL syntax;
check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near
''{\"cc_session_id\":\"6c4kst3dcgn7od7lmlu6o5lio5\",\"cc_action\":\"cca_editroste' at line 1
```

Comment: Mysql parser shows first thing it does not understand and some parts after it, but to know why it is an error, you usually need to check what was before it, so get some text editor/viewer which will be able to show you the line 125596 and some context to it. From this we can only guess - It looks like JSON so maybe quote escaping is wrong?

Comment: can we use mysql -f option when restoring to force the restore and continue even if there is error ?

Comment: You may try, but but I am not sure it will work on syntax error (that might mean skipping a lot of rows/statements in some cases - imagine missing quote, then 100 rows without quotes and then one with it - mysql sees a statement with really long string value which is malformed, so everything in between gets skipped if it just continues on next one). Afaik -f is meant for skipping FK/unique etc errors.